# Broken grommet on transfer case

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, transfer-case

[image: Broken grommet][image: Broken grommet on transfer case]

I have a 2004 Chevy Silverado 2500 HD. It has 222,000 miles on it. I was wondering what this was an how do I replace it?

Comment: If you grab the driveshaft yoke and move it up/down or left/right, is there movement? The reason I ask is, the metal piece between the seal (end of the transfer case) and whatever that notched piece is, looks like the bushing which holds the yoke in position inside of the transfer. Does that piece turn on the yoke?